# haskell, is number in one list is within the range of a second list?

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

What is the best way to find out if a number in a list is within the range of a second list, using a Maybe data type?

What I have so far:

```
getElems :: [Int] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
getElems [xs] ys
    | head(tail[(xs)]) > head(tail[(ys)]) = [Nothing]
    | otherwise = [Just xs]
```

It needs to return those elements that correspond to the positions specified. Depending on if a position is greater than the list size it returns Nothing, else Just value.

For example:

```
getElems [2,4] [1..10] ) [Just 3,Just 5]
getElems [2,4] [1..4] ) [Just 3,Nothing]
```

Comment: Note that `[xs]` matches a single-element list, assigning its only value to the name `xs`.  You probably want something more like `getElems xs ys` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can write an `getElementByIndex` which does that for a single list:

```
getElementByIndex :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
getElementByIndex n [] = Nothing
getElementByIndex n (x:xs) = if (n == 0)
                             then Just x
                             else getElementByIndex (n - 1) xs
```

And then just `map` it to get an answer:

```
getElems :: [Int] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
getElems xs ys = map (\x -> getElementByIndex x ys) xs
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> getElems [2,4] [1..10]
[Just 3,Just 5]
λ> getElems [2,4] [1..4]
[Just 3,Nothing]
```

Comment: You can also do it like this `getElems xs ys = map (listToMaybe . flip drop ys) xs`